# Crashreport for c++ library show missing

Tags: android, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I have configured build.gradle and Application to make Crashlytics works.
But not able to figure out why the c++ code is showing "missing" and no any detail information(line number, call stack). 
"./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsdevelopmentRelease" succeed without any error.
The stack trace of java code crash report works. Only crash report of c++ code show "missing".

[image] 
   The "libengine" is used by Java code through JNI.

```
build by:
externalNativeBuild {
   cmake {
      path "CMakeLists.txt"
   }
}


my build.gradle:
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'build/intermediates/cmake/development/debug/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'build/intermediates/cmake/development/release/obj'
    manifestPath 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
```

Comment: Do you have access to the unstripped, debug version of these libraries?

Comment: @MikeBonnell  Yes, i have. The debug version is in "build/intermediates/cmake/development/debug/obj" directory.   I had also run ./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsdevelopmentDebug to upload that.

Comment: Ok and which versions of our SDK and gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: @MikeBonnell dependencies {  
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:2.0.5') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

Comment: @MikeBonnell  I didn't figure out how to list the plugin version of io.fabric ? Where i can get it ?  I use the the fabric Android studio plugin to automatically add all such configuration, it should be the default or latest.*

Comment: Hey Roc - look for this line or somthing similar  classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

Comment: Hi, i have a exact same line in my build.gradle "classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'"

Comment: @MikeBonnell Hi, i have a exact same line in my build.gradle "classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'"

Comment: Gotcha, in your build.log of Crashlytics do you see the library symbols being uploaded?

Comment: @MikeBonnell  where i can find that build.log ?  In webpage of fabric.io or my android app project directory ?

Comment: Ahh, sorry. On Linux / Windows:~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.logOn Mac:~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log

Comment: @MikeBonnell  i saw "com.crashlytics  - cSYM file(s) uploaded." in the log file.

Comment: @MikeBonnell  The issue is even worse now, the (c++ code) crash is not shown in Crashlytics.

Comment: @MikeBonnell   I make a test code which using null pointer in 1 minute after  app startup in Samsung tablet, The app crashed but no any crash report is shown in Crashlytics.   Where i can check the crash file do generated in Samsung android tablet and it was uploaded to Crashlytics?  It is very strange, i still can get java crash report. Now i believe the symbol are uploaded successfully, but i dont get crash report any more.

Comment: @MikeBonnell  Is the c++ crash report taken longer time to be processed and shown in Crashlytics ?  How long ?

Comment: Hey Roc - I believe you were affected by this production issue on our end: http://status.fabric.io/incidents/0hf9twr1rb74 Crashes should be flowing in now.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thank you so much. Now it works, i can see the c++ file line number and call stack.

Comment: correct one configuration for later readers, should be :  crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'build/intermediates/cmake/development/release/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'build/intermediates/transforms/stripDebugSymbol/development/release/0/lib'
}

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the wrong path for the obj and lib in build.gradle.
In my case, the c++ library is built by cmake, i should configure as below for uploading symbol for release build.

```
    crashlytics {
        enableNdk true
        androidNdkOut 'build/intermediates/cmake/development/release/obj'
        androidNdkLibsOut 'build/intermediates/transforms/stripDebugSymbol/development/release/0/lib'
        manifestPath 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    #in order to avoid manually run crashlyticsUploadsSymbols
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def variantName = variant.name.capitalize()
        if(variant.buildType.name=="release")
        variant.assemble.finalizedBy(project.("crashlyticsUploadSymbols${variantName}"))
    }
```

I learned to check if uploading succeed by checking:

```
~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools/crashlytics.log
```